# Android swipe activity list

Tags: android, swipe

I have worked on "swipe" in android 3.0 and it's working fine. Now after swipping some pages(suppose to the right) I want all those pages to appear at the bottom(as options) so that I don't have to swipe all the pages (to the left) to get back to first page. I can directly select the desired page from those options and jump on to that activity.
Please help or tell me any good tutorial which can help.
Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

Put some container layout at the bottom, add a listener to the swipe event, where you inflate / generate dynamically a corresponding item and add it to the container in the bottom. Add a click listener to the item, and in the click listener emulate swipe to the corresponding page...